# Tracking changes in abstractbox, figure and table environments with "changes"

Tags: environments, changes, trackchanges

I use the changes package for tracking changes for a publication in a journal. Everything works smoothly, but I have problems that the changes can be included in the environments (figure, table, abstractbox), but the remarks cannot be displayed or this leads to error messages.

```
\documentclass{bmcart}

%%% Load packages
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
%\RequirePackage{natbib}
%\RequirePackage[authoryear]{natbib}% uncomment this for author-year bibliography
%\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

%%% tracking changes + settings
\usepackage[markup=underlined]{changes}
\definechangesauthor[color=green]{Author}
\definechangesauthor[color=blue]{R1}
\definechangesauthor[color=red]{R2}
\reversemarginpar
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3.5cm}

%% Use "final" option to remove all tracking markups
% \usepackage[final]{changes}

%%% Alternative definition to have the remarks
%%% in the margins instead of footnotes
\usepackage{todonotes}
\setcommentmarkup{\todo[color={authorcolor!20},size=\scriptsize]{#3: #1}}

%%% Begin ...
\begin{document}

%%% Start of article front matter
\begin{frontmatter}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                          %%
%% Enter the title of your article here     %%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Tracking Changes}

\begin{abstractbox}

\begin{abstract} % abstract
\parttitle{Background} %if any
bla bla
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\parttitle{Method} %if any
bla bla
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\parttitle{Results} %if any
\replaced[id=R1,comment={1.1: I want more bla bla}]{new bla bla}{bla bla}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\parttitle{Conclusions} %if any
bla bla 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{abstract}

\end{abstractbox}
\end{frontmatter}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% start of article main body
%
% --- Background ---
%
\section*{Background}
bla bla

\end{document}
```

Results in the error message:

```
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.551 \clearpage
                
You've lost some text.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

If I take `[id=R1,comment={1.1: I want more bla bla}]` out, everything compiles without errors, but then I don't have a comment box at the appropriate place. The same applies to figures and tables.

I have already experimented a lot and have not found a solution.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I have now added the whole preamble and a workaround to make the context easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was now able to solve the problem myself. After some research and trial and error, the following approach works:

```
\usepackage{marginnote}\let\marginpar\marginnote
```

This allows to use the changes-package in figure, table and the abstractbox environments.